# Running a system command from a perl cgi only works on the first foreach loop

Tags: html, perl, cgi

This is a foreach loop which I have in a cgi perl script. The cgi excecutes correctly, prints out each variable, but only does the sed/sort system command once.

If I run the following, I generate the html page below with an array size 3, but only tmpsort1.txt is generated. All inputs have been checked and verified.

```
foreach $path (@paths){
        $i++;
        print "$path\t";
        $command = "sed 's/ (.*)//' $path | sort -k1 >/var/www/analyses/tmp/tmpsort$i.txt";
        print "$command\t";
        system("$command");
        print "$path<br>";
}
```

input path --- System command --- re-checking the input path

```
printed variables into the html page:
    /var/www/analyses/abun/100_genus_proportion sed 's/ (.*)//' /var/www/analyses/abun/100_genus_proportion | sort -k1 >/var/www/tmp/tmpsort1.txt /var/www/analyses/abun/100_genus_proportion
    /var/www/analyses/abun/113_genus_proportion sed 's/ (.*)//' /var/www/analyses/abun/113_genus_proportion | sort -k1 >/var/www/tmp/tmpsort2.txt /var/www/analyses/abun/113_genus_proportion
    /var/www/analyses/abun/55_genus_proportion  sed 's/ (.*)//' /var/www/analyses/abun/55_genus_proportion | sort -k1 >/var/www/tmp/tmpsort3.txt /var/www/analyses/abun/55_genus_proportion
```

Just to confirm, only /var/www/tmp/tmpsort1.txt is being created. The others do not exist after running the script. All permissions are correct.

Edit: Just to add, I've tried it with the sed and sort commands separated out into separate calls and I am getting the same result.

Comment: What does your webserver log say about errors? You can open STDERR to print to a file to make it easier to check errors.

Comment: Also, you don't have newlines in your `$path` right? It would not show up on the html output, but would still break your commands.

Comment: I've got as many lines as there are failures of: 
**`sed: read error on /var/www/analyses/abun/: Is a directory`**

but it's definitely succeeding in the first instance (to remove some text within brackets) then sorting, so I don't understand how it can be broken after that. I have checked the source and there are no newlines too. 
Thanks for the input.

Comment: Use `Data::Dumper` to print the `$path` instead: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper \@paths;` it will show you the whitespace you cannot see, but is clearly there.

Comment: That's really helped, thanks. I dont think it's whitespace, but theres a weird \0 that's in the middle of the failing paths but not in the working one:
/var/www/analyses/abun/\0NGS/113_genus_proportion

Comment: That directory (which I cut out of the original question to keep it short on the page) is one of the options which I get back from the form  POST submit, so I think it must add something in somehow... I'll need to look into it.

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: Absolutely solved, Thank you so much. The error went all the way back to my parsing of the POST stream. I wasn't aware of the 'null byte' separator and that's what was breaking the path. I've parsed it correctly now and it's all happy. I'll write up the solution tomorrow to put in the answers. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: In the future use perl and not bash to do things.... everything done in this script could have been accomplished in perl